# styling loaded content jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-mobile

i am working on asp.net page with jquery mobile 1.3 I am generating  asp.net checkbox and label controls using vb. then i am using java script to converting the asp label to label. all the code looks fine but my control not being style (jquerymobile). so after my page load and java script that what i get.

```
<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_chkbox2" type="checkbox"name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chkbox2">
<label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_chkbox2">YES</label>
```

but not styled as jquery mobile check boxes how can i style the dynamic controls.

> I tried:

```
$('#page1').trigger('create');`
$('#page1').page();
```

nothing work. please help Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer

To change text of `type=checkbox` or `type=radio`:

```
$('label[for=name]').find('span.ui-btn-text').text('New Text');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Pauph/)** includes:

- Change text
- Add/create new checkbox, using `.checkboxradio().trigger('create');`
- Dynamically 'Check/Uncheck' checkbox, using `.prop('check', true);` and `.checkboxradio('refresh);`

---

Refresh checkbox or radio buttons this way

```
$('[type=checkbox]').checkboxradio('refresh')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't work with me. maybe i am doing it wrong here is my js  $(document).ready(function () {  jQuery.each($(".span"), function () {

                so_classes = $(this).attr("for");
                $(this).replaceWith("<label for=" + so_classes + ">" + $(this).text() + "</label>");
              
            });  $('[type=checkbox]').checkboxradio('refresh')
        });